# Free issue tracking/project management that works with Visual Source Safe

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, issue-tracking

I know [VSS is awful](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000660.html), I am just a cog in the great machine of life and have learned to live with feelings of powerlessness with the help of a therapist. However, I'd like to bring some order to the chaos here, and a real issue tracking/project management system like [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBUGZ/) that integrates with VSS would be a huge improvement. The problem with Fogbugz is cost: I'm never going to convince my department to spend a penny on this, and I'll have to champion whatever free solution I choose until I pass out in a puddle of tears.

So, [what's out there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems) that's free (as in beer), that integrates with VSS, that you've used, that you like (or at least only barely hate)?

Comment: Not really, to be honest I don't see it as the vast improvement over VSS that Jeff Atwood does. Doesn't matter anyway, as I am not in charge of which SCM system we use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gemini](http://www.countersoft.com/products/gemini.aspx) works with VSS, and is excellent for bug/issue tracking. It's free for up to 5 users.

Comment: Downloaded that, couldn't get it to run. Ran the installer, made all sorts of config changes to IIS on my workstation (XP), it's still producing errors. Since I'll end up supporting whatever I choose solo, I've got to have something I can evaluate without hassle. So, Gemini's out unfortunately. If I can't find something better, I'll wade into it again.

Comment: I've always found the install to be hassle free; what errors are you seeing?

Comment: @Chris McCall: seems there is something wrong with your XP installation. I suggest you insert the XP install disk and preform a repair.